# Does a c++ program automatically free memory when it crashes?

Tags: c++, exception, memory

I read in Google c++ coding standards that Google does not use exception. If exception is not used, how do you free memory when errors occur in your program?

For example, f() calls g(), and if there is error in g(), I should free all memory allocated in g(), and then call an exception to f(). Once f() catches the exception, f() will free all memory allocated in f(), and exits the program.

If exception is not used, and if there is an error in g(), can I force exit `exit(0)`, and will the c++ program be smart enough to free all memory that is allocated? My guess is, since c++ maintain a stack and heap, and once the program exits, c++ will automatically free both stack and heap?

Comment: It's the OS that reclaims the memory, typically.

Comment: well if the whole process crashes, then yes, the memory is freed by the os. no matter what language the program was written in.

Comment: Arguably it's a bit fraudulent to claim something is C++ if you forbid exceptions. It's like offering your driver a car but only if he uses no fuel.

Comment: @Kerrek: *arguably* it's fraudulent to claim something is C++03 if you forbid `export` for templates. It's really just a question of whether your code base does or does not use the feature. The difference is that Google doesn't use exceptions, and most people do, whereas nobody (plus or minus a small error term) uses `export`. Even Google doesn't claim that this decision on their part was a *good* one, but it's a consistent style. It gets you from A to B, just not in comfort.

Comment: @Steve: Maybe, but it's definitely more than *style*. Exception handling is a fundamental idiom that underpins most of the standard library (think allocators) and class design fundamentals (single responsibility with exception-induced automatic clean-up). `export` is the fluffy cube on the rearview mirror whose absence I can tolerate... :-)

Comment: I wonder how much Google's coding style was influenced by the ex-Symbian engineers they hired a few years ago. The coding standards are quite similar.

Comment: It doesn't matter so much why the Google style guide is that way, but more that it *sucks horrendously* for the average project.

Answer (score 10):

The operating system cleans up all used memory and file handles when a process is terminated for whatever reason.

Answer (score -1):

I have heard that some memory types like, on Windows, COM global heap memory cannot be freed for you. However, *most* memory/handles are cleaned up, because the OS has to cope with the condition that your application crashed. You can certainly guarantee it in the case of process-local memory and most handles like file handles, etc. In the general case, you can assume that the OS will clean up after you when your application exits.

Also, don't ever, ever follow Google's style guide. It's not for C++, it's for C++ minus everything you have to take away to make it C. It might work for Google (dubiously), but it definitely won't work for anyone else.