# program terminates with dynamic memory on the heap

Tags: c++, c, dynamic-memory-allocation

I will preface this question to c/c++ as it mostly pertains to that, and I have seen it have the most impact with c/c++.

this has concerned me for some time, and I understand some of this problem can be avoided (and I would like to avoid the lectures on ways to avoid, but rather focus on the aftermath just in case it does happen), but I would still have the underlying question.

initial thoughts:

A pointer simply serves as a address to an object somewhere else in memory (this can be because of needing to modify the number of things of that type `int[]`, or because the nature of the thing can change throughout the lifespan of the thing `polymophism`)

anytime the keyword `new` is used it should have a corresponding keyword `delete` (if not multiple depending on exception handling, and multiple exit points)

when a dynamically allocated memory chunk is acted upon by keyword `delete` the destructor is called (and its actions are performed if any), the memory chunk is returned to the system store to be made available for other things, and (depending on compiler, macros, or programmer) the pointer is set to `NULL` to avoid illegal memory accessing.

situation:

when I am writing a program that uses dynamic memory (combination of `pointers`, `new`, and `delete`). if something happens, and the program terminates unexpectedly (unhandled exception, memory access error, illegal operation. etc). the system should attempt to remove all memory that the program is using, and return it to the system, but pointers are not always cleared. this may vary between operating system, and compiler (on how program termination is performed), but the things that were pointed to may still exist in memory because all that was deleted was the pointer, and not the thing that was pointed to. granted this can be quite small loss (less then a MB for a small program, but for say stress testing a data store, or processing large files this can be quite large possibly even in the GB range.

the direct question is what steps can be taken to get that memory back? the only thing that I have found that works is to just restart the system (this is when using g++, and VS2008/2010 on a windows system)

Comment: Are you talking about the memory being assigned to the program being freed? If so, then the os guarantees that the memory is freed. See : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7472914/does-a-c-program-automatically-free-memory-when-it-crashes

Comment: @jasonzhu though I have seen the opposite in that when a program terminates (and only that program was running)all remnants of the program stop displaying (including the window in a VS instance) the system can see a performance drag, and if things like this happen enough, or to a high degree then the program will not run, and window will even throw "not enough memory", and when the system is rebooted it runs normally. I understand what "should" happen, but I just have a feeling it isn't, and would like to know how to correct it.

Comment: Freeing of memory when a Windows process terminates is not just something that "should" happen. It does happen. So either your program is not actually terminating, or the resource that's being leaked is something other than dynamically allocated memory.

Comment: @paulMitchell I can watch my process list, and my memory profile, and see if a program terminates that the process is being removed, but my memory profile still shows a portion of the memory not returned, and still in use, but there is no process that is using it, and the memory profile, and process list totals do not match (only noticeable with large programs, and accepting some fluctuations) even after terminating IDE

Comment: There is the issue of shared memory and memory allocated via mmap which may not be eliminated, otherwise I am not sure.

Comment: I started to edit this and try to fix fundamental forming of sentences, but as I did so I realize that the contents of the text aren't even coherent and I don't understand what it says. Vote to close.

Answer (score 4):

If the program terminates, then all memory it was using is returned to the system.  At least under Windows which you say you are using.  If you think this is not happening, then perhaps your program is not actually terminating at all.

Comment: though I have seen the opposite in that when a program terminates (and only that program was running)all remnants of the program stop displaying (including the window in a VS instance) the system can see a performance drag, and if things like this happen enough, or to a high degree then the program will not run, and window will even throw "not enough memory"

Answer (score 1):

The heap is bound to the allocator, and the allocator is bound to the process. When the process exits, the heap comes undone. Only system-shared resources aren't deallocated.